# Sed command to replace file path in txt file

Tags: linux, sed

Good day all!

I am trying to change the path of directories in a text file using sed cmd.

The servers I have tested the commands are running Rocky Linux 8.5 (Green Obsidian).

Here's the sed command I am using:

```
sed -i 's|1344P1052_ssl02 /gs:/prod1|sd://prod1-backup|g' example.txt

sed -i 's|1344P1052_ssl09 /gs:/prod1|sd://prod1-backup|g' example.txt
```

There is no error in the output, but the directory path in the file remains the same.

It should change [example below]

Before:

```
1344P1052_ssl02 /gs:/prod1/some_notes_here_1
1344P1052_ssl09 /gs:/prod1/some_notes_here_2
```

After:

```
sd://prod1-backup/some_notes_here_1
sd://prod1-backup/some_notes_here_2
```

I think it does not work because of the space, semi-colons, etc but I googled in this group's answer and read that using `|`

should work for special chars, backslash and space. Now I am not too sure, so I am just doing it manually with vim line by line.

Appreciate any help really...

Comment: Don't use `|` as separator for `s` in `vim`. `|` there separates commands.

Comment: It works for me with GNU sed on your sample. Maybe that space is a TAB in your actual input. You can check with `sed -n l example.txt`

Comment: @Kusalananda the input is 2 lines, and the output is also 2 lines of the same result ```sd://prod1-backup/some_notes_here```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes i just checked and it is a TAB! is that why sed is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your substitution fails because the two columns in your input file are tab-delimited, not space-delimited.

Instead of a space in your regular expression, you may use a literal tab character (typed on the command line using <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>), or you may use an expression that represents a tab, such as `[[:blank:]]` (matches a single tab or space character) or `[[:space:]]` (matches a single character from a larger set of space-like characters, including horizontal and vertical tabs, carriage-returns, etc.)

```bash
sed -e 's|^1344P1052_ssl02[[:blank:]]/gs:/prod1/|sd://prod1-backup/|' \
    -e 's|^1344P1052_ssl09[[:blank:]]/gs:/prod1/|sd://prod1-backup/|' \
    -i example.txt
```

or, even shorter,

```bash
sed -e 's|^1344P1052_ssl0[29][[:blank:]]/gs:/prod1/|sd://prod1-backup/|' \
    -i example.txt
```

- I've replaced the space in your pattern with `[[:blank:]]`.  This allows for a single space-or-tab character at that point in the text.
- I have also combined the two substitutions into a single `sed` call to avoid reading the whole file twice.
- I deleted the `g` flag on both substitution commands as we don't ever expect to make more than a single substitution per line.
- I added a `^` anchor to ensure that the patterns match at the start of each line.
- I added a `/` at the end of the pattern and replacement string to not accidentally change lines relating to `prod10` or higher-numbered `prod` things.

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` is only space+tab in the C/POSIX locale. In other locales, it often matches a lot more (though not ASCII ones)

Comment: @kusalananda thank you so much!! That worked and I managed to rename all the dir paths in the file. I have a follow up question. is it possible to use wildcard or something for ```1344P1052_ssl0``` because in one text file, this directory path can be different. like ```1589P1856_ssl9``` and so forth.

Comment: @PritiPatel I showed how to combine the pattern for `1344P1052_ssl02` and `1344P1052_ssl09` into `1344P1052_ssl0[29]`.  If you want to allow for any two-digit integer, use `1344P1052_ssl[0-9][0-9]`.  If you want to allow for any integer regardless of how many digits (including no digits), use `1344P1052_ssl[0-9]*`.

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry for the confusion. I meant the whole string ```1344P1052_ssl09``` regardless of its name and integer. I replaced ```'s|^1344P1052_ssl0[29]``` with ```'s|^*``` but that didn't work.

Comment: @PritiPatel `s|.*[[:blank:]]/gs:/prod1/|sd://prod1-backup/|`

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for that! I added the ```^``` like so ```'s|^.*``` because of the TAB I have at the beginning of that file and it worked like charm!

Comment: @PritiPatel Since `.*` matches any length of any string (including tabs, spaces and other characters), it would always start matching at the start of the line if it occurs first in the regular expression.  It is therefore unnecessary to add `^` at the start of the expression if it starts with `.*`.

Comment: @Kusalananda many thanks, I managed to do a basic shell to pass source and destination file path to rename and also the text file to edit.
```SOURCE=wg-prodX/ab06
DEST=sd:prodX
FILE_PATH=file.txt```

```sed -i -e "s|.*[[:blank:]]/gs:/$SOURCE|$DEST|" -i $FILE_PATH```

Comment: @PritiPatel It's a pity that you did not ask about what you _actually_ wanted to do in your question.  There are safer ways to do this that does not involve code injection vulnerabilities or restrictions in what characters a filename may contain.  Treating the input as CSV rather than as text would allow us to use a CSV-aware tool to handle the data properly.  I'm also noting that you included the unneeded `^` at the start of the expression.

Comment: @Kusalananda well, there is no CSV file. Just a txt file that contains a list of index files that were transferred using an app on Windows. I just have to update it manually in the backend [Linux] to make sure it tallies with the Windows's transfer. That is all. PS-- I was also trying to avoid using VIM to edit line-by-line.